# Making videojs player fit the div dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, video.js

I have react application in which I have a page with media player and other components on the side. I have made a div to fit the player in it like this.

[image]

It is just an empty div right now. Here is part of my component where full page is defined

```
return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <div className='video-section'>
                    <div className='video-container'>
                    <div className='video-player'></div>

                </div>
                    <div className='video-title'> {name} </div>
                    <div className='process-list'>
                        {
                            PROCESS_LIST.map((x,i)=> (
                                <div 
                                    className='process-item' 
                                    key={i}> {x} </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='details-section'>
                    <VideoDetails/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Here is the css of this component

```
:local(.container)
    display flex
    flex 1

    .video-section
        margin 24px
        flex 1
    .details-section
        margin 24px
        width 33vw
        flex-shrink 0
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        // border-left 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid

    .video-container
        width 100%
        background-color #000
        ratio-box(16/8)
    .video-title
        font-size 2.4em
        margin-top 4vh
        margin-bottom 4vh

    .video-section .process-list
        display flex
        width 100%

        .process-item
            flex 1
            background-color #D7D7D7
            padding 18px 30px
            font-size 1em
            text-align center
            border-radius 8px
            margin 0 4px
            cursor pointer
            &:hover
                background-color darken(@background-color, 10%)


:local(.container)
    .video-details-container
        flex 1
        display flex
        flex-direction column

    .comments-section, .tabbed-section
        min-height 100px
        background-color #fff
        border 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid
        box-shadow 0 4px 24px 0 rgba(#000, 0.12)
    .comments-section
        height 180px

    .flex-vertical
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        height 100%

    .flex-fill
        flex 1

    .tabbed-section
        flex 1
        margin-bottom 20px
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        .tab-content
            flex 1

    .table-footer, .comments-footer
        clearfix()
        text-align right
        padding 10px
        border-top 1px rgba(#000, 0.2) solid

    #comments-input
        flex 1
        border none
        padding 20px
        outline none


    .flags-table 
        .red-box
            width 16px
            height 16px
            margin 3px 5px
            background-color red
```

So now when I put a  which is a videojs player, in the div like this, It doesn't fit into the black box. VideoJs has it's own width and height props defined in my code currently. But when I remove those props thinking that js will automatically take the dimensions of black box, that doesn't happen. It gets abnormal dimensions. I am also including my video js code abstract.

```
<div className={c.container}>
                <div className='video-section'>
                    <div className='video-container'>
                        <Player/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='video-title'> {name} </div>
```

videojs

```
assign(props, {
            ref: 'video',
            controls: true,
            width: "960", height: "600"
        });


        return (
            <div>
                <video {... props}>
                    <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type} id={this.props.id}/>
                </video>
            </div>)

    }
```

Updated view after including player in video-player div.

[image]

Updates

After doing this

```
.video-container
        position: relative
        width: 500px
        height: 300px

    .video-player
        position absolute
        width 50vw
        height 30vh

<div className='video-section'>
                    <div className='video-container'>
                        <div className='video-player'>
                            <Player/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I still get this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: use !important to override the default position of the video.

Comment: @Codesingh Where? can you please add it in my videojs code and give it as answer. Would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the below style to video player div:

//!important to disable default style
//set width as per your requirement

```
.video-player {
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Cheers:)

Comment: The point is I don't have "video-player" div after I include <Player/>. I add <Player/> in the place of video-player div. Are you saying I should put <Player/> in video-player div?

Comment: Not working. I adding screenshot of what it looks like after doing exactly what u suggested

Comment: did you change the width ?

Comment: assign(props, {
            ref: 'video',
            controls: true,
            width: "auto", height:"auto",
            class:" "
        });

Comment: made it auto. And include the code u gave in styl file.

Comment: what was expected ?

Comment: Expected was to see video player in the place of black box (which is a div with classname "video-player". I included it in ques/

Comment: ok remove video-player div and apply the above style inside video-container

Comment: can we take this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133144/discussion-between-codesingh-and-apurvg).